# Fade In Image On Load Via CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on a web app. When a user visits the landing page, I want to fade-in an image. That image is the background for some text. When the image has successfully loaded, I then want to move the text in from the top. Currently, I have the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .banner {
        background-image: url('/public/img/bg.png');
        background-size: cover
      }

      @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }}

      .fade-in {
        opacity:0;
        animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
        animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        animation-duration:0.2s;            
      }

      @keyframes translateY { from { y:0px; } to { y:100px; } }
      .translate-y {
        animation:translateY ease-in 1;
        animation-duration:0.1s;
        animation-fill-mode:forwards;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="banner fade-in">
      <h1 class="translate-y">Welcome</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are several problems with this approach:

1. The animation starts whether the background-image is loaded or not.
2. The "Welcome" text starts animating before the background-image is loaded.

I'm not sure how to fix this. The first item is especially frustrating. I can't use jQuery, so I'm stuff with CSS. The second item, I could use an offset. However, once again, if the image isn't cached, nothing runs properly.

Comment: CSS doesn't know wether your image is loaded or not. You have to use Javascript

Comment: Can you use Javascript?

Comment: I would add JS image.onload that just adds the class to start the animation once image has loaded, that is if you can use JS in whatever you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this problem before, there is a solution I have used myself from this [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/), but just in case the link does go dead here is the solution: You need to add a class/id to your body to ensure that everything transitions/animations and anything you need CSS runs after the body loads. The below is an example of what you can achieve, keep in mind you can add anything else you need under the `#preload` id.

CSS

```
#preload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<body id="preload">
```

JS

```
// trigger right as the document loads
document.getElementById("preload").className = "";
```

Give it a try and let us know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 12):

Place your image in the background with an `<img ...>` tag, (not with CSS `background-image: ...` attribute).

You can set the initial opacity to 0, and when the image `onload`ed, set the opacity to 1. With CSS you can make a transition between the two states:

```html
<style>
.easeload{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 2s ease; 
}
</style>

<img class="easeload" onload="this.style.opacity=1" src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240">
```

Comment: Note: if you are using SSR, the `onload` event might fire before the hydration finishes, so it won't be captured. You might want adding a fallback timeout or other measures to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animation-delay` and add it to the elements.It should solve your problems :

```
animation-delay: 2s;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, because you're assuming the image will load in 2 seconds. What if it takes 5 seconds? Or .5 seconds? The problem persists.